# cannot implicitly convert string to string[]. in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

while assigning string(here `dbnm`) to string array(here `admin_database`), an error is shown that
'cannot implicitly convert string to string[].'

```
List<string[]> admin_database=new List<string[]>();
string dbnm;

admin_database[db_index] = dbnm
```

is there any method to convert/cast `string` to `string[]` in c#?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? You use `admin_database.Add()` to add to your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string dbnm = "bla-bla";

var admin_database = new List<string>();   
admin_database.Add(dbnm);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for other readers.